# Why my Django south can not migrate for no unique constraint matching?

Tags: python, django, unique, django-south

My user class is:

```
class PMUser(models.Model):

   username = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text='Required. Maximum 30 characters.')
   firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text='Enter first name.')
   lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text='Enter last name.')
   contactnumber = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, help_text='Telephone number or mobile number.')
   email = models.EmailField(unique=True,help_text='Enter email address.')
```

my attemptlogin class is:

```
class AccessAttempt( models.Model ):
    loginname = models.CharField('loginname', max_length=255)
    user=models.ForeignKey(PMUser, null=True, unique=True)
    failures = models.PositiveIntegerField( 'Failures', default=0 )
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField( 'Last failed attempt', null=True,auto_now=True )
```

when I try to use Django South to build the new AccessAttempt table:

```
 C:\workspace\pmode>python manage.py schemamigration pmauth --auto
 + Added field user on pmauth.AccessAttempt
 Created 0003_auto__add_field_accessattempt_user.py. You can now apply this migra
 tion with: ./manage.py migrate pmauth

 C:\workspace\pmode>python manage.py migrate pmauth
 Running migrations for pmauth:
 - Migrating forwards to 0003_auto__add_field_accessattempt_user.
 > pmauth:0003_auto__add_field_accessattempt_user
 FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: ALTER TABLE "auth_accessattempt" A
 DD CONSTRAINT "user_id_refs_id_9d1b56dc" FOREIGN KEY ("user_id") REFERENCES "aut
 h_pmuser" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
 The error was: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced
 table "auth_pmuser"

 Error in migration: pmauth:0003_auto__add_field_accessattempt_user
 DatabaseError: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced
 table "auth_pmuser"
```

is that problem is I do not defined the user_id yet in table(class)PMUser as unique key?
how to solve it?

Comment: What are the other models in the `pmauth` app? I'm not having any problem migrating this as the initial migration, so the problem is probably happening in an earlier migration.

Comment: there is no other models matter in pmauth app, because if I delete the  user=models.ForeignKey(PMUser, null=True, unique=True) the migrate can work all-right.

Comment: If there are no other models, then how is this the third migration?

Comment: the second migration is I do not add the user field in AccessAttempt class, which is no error, the third one is error when I add the user field on it